# discord.py based bot doesn't work after 2.0 update

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was used to use this bot about one year ago, now I wanted to launch it again but after discord.py 2.0 update it seems doesn't work propery

```
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('bot is online now', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['ffs','gdsgds']


        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send('Do not say that!')

     

# keep_alive()
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run('OTkxfsa9WC5G34')
```

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread 

app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return 'dont forget uptime robot monitor'

def run():
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8000)

def keep_alive():
  t = Thread(target=run)
  t.start()
```

I tried to fix it by my own by changing this line

`client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())`

It has to be some trivial syntax mistake, but I cannot locate it

Edit1: so i turned on intents in bot developer portal and made my code to looks like this but still seems something doesn't work

```
import discord
from keep_alive import keep_alive
class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('bot is online now', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        word_list = ['fdsfds','fsa']


        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            for word in word_list:
                if word in messageContent:
                    await message.delete()
                    await message.channel.send('Do not say that!')

     

# keep_alive()
intents = discord.Intents.default()                  
intents.message_content = True                  
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)
client.run('OTkxMDcxMTUx')
```

Answer (score 2):

If it would be a syntax mistake you'd get a syntax error. The real issue is that you didn't enable the message_content intent, so you can't read the content of messages. `Intents.default()` doesn't include privileged intents.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Don't forget to enable it on your bot's developer portal as well.

Also all of that keep alive & flask stuff hints that you're abusing an online host to run a bot on. This brings loads of issues along with it that you *can't fix* so you should really consider moving away from that. There's posts on a daily basis of people with problems caused by this.

Comment: so i followed all of these recommendations except about keep alive and flask. The result i get now is:
INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 24e23d95c57c650f6fb594c6d5bf780c).

seems something still doesn't work properly

Comment: @Diegunio no that's a good sign. It says INFO, not ERROR, so it's just providing you with some info about what's happening. That message specifically tells you that your bot connected to Discord's gateway, which is a **good** sign indicating that it **did** work properly.

Comment: @Diegunio in your new code you're running the `discord.Client` class. You should use your own subclass (you called it `MyClient`) instead. If anything else isn't behaving the way you're expecting, that's probably why. You're not using it. Instead of creating a `discord.Client` instance, create a `MyClient` instance.

Answer (score -2):

Your code should be:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands # you need to import this to be able to use commands and events
from keep_alive import keep_alive
client = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): # you don't need self in here
    print('bot is online now', client.user) # you can just use client.user

@bot.event
async def on_message(message): # again, you do not need self
    word_list = ['ffs','gdsgds']
    if message.author == client.user: # you can use client.user here too
        return
    messageContent = message.content
    if len(messageContent) > 0:
        for word in word_list:
            if word in messageContent:
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send('Do not say that!')

keep_alive()
client.run('OTkxfsa9WC5G34') #if this is your real token/you have been using this token since you made the bot, you should definitely generate a new one
```

To help you, I added some comments to help show you what I have changed and why. As one of the comments in the code says, you should regenerate your bot token at [the Discord Developer Portal.](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

For more info about migrating to 2.0, [read the Discord.Py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html)

Comment: Basically everything in this answer is wrong or unnecessary

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'

Comment: @Diegunio Just change `commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.default())` to `commands.Bot(command_prefix="your command prefix goes here", intents=discord.Intents.default())`. For example, if you set your command prefix to "?", then in the Discord chat you would type "?command_goes_here".